# PHP is hanging only after server reboot

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04, apache2.4, php-7.3

I recently upgraded from php 7.0 to 7.3, to finalise this I did the following

```
a2dismod php7.0
a2enmod php7.3
service apache2 restart
```

This works fine, and `phpinfo()` shows I am now using 7.3.

However after a system reboot any php function hangs, this includes CLI.

To "fix" this I can do "a2dismod php7.3" *without restarting apache2 service* which for some reason brings my php CLI functionality and websites back online and running 7.3 - though if I do "service apache2 restart" it does disable php as you would now expect

I am unsure why this is happening and can find nothing in logs.

```
(PHP 7.3.11-1+ubuntu16.04)
a2dismod php7.0
a2enmod php7.3
service apache2 restart
```

No error messages appear, if I try `php -v` it will hang indefinitely.

Comment: Maybe your process is consuming 100% of CPU that is why it is hanging.

Comment: After a reboot, are maybe both php7.0 and php7.3 enabled?